# Inherit typeclass with a function with the same name

Tags: haskell

I have a inheritance of typeclasses with a function with the same name, but different types.

Code:

```
class Equatable a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool

class Equatable key => Entity key where
    (==) :: (Entity key) -> (Entity key) -> Bool
```

Error:

> Multiple declarations of `=='

I am trying to simulate the next code in C#:

```
public class Equatable<T>
{
    public static bool ==(T type1, T type2)
    { … }
}

public class Entity<TKey> : Equatable<TKey>
{
    public static bool ==(Entity<TKey> type1, Entity<TKey> type2)
    { … }
}
```

Comment: That first one looks like the wrong type: should be `a -> a  -> Bool`. After that, though, it looks like you are misunderstanding typeclasses entirely, because this sort of inheritance makes no sense, and neither does your second typeclass definition. [Typeclasses are more like interfaces than classes](https://wiki.haskell.org/OOP_vs_type_classes#Type_classes_vs_classes).

Comment: @amalloy I have read it and fixed the typo. My point is, when I compare against a instance of Entity, I want apply determinated function, and when I compare against Equatable, I want apply a general function.

Comment: Type classes in Haskell work very differently than OO classes. When you have a type, you can have it implement the interface of a type class. Type classes are not themselves types. The Haskell code you have here doesn’t really make sense because you don’t need the second type class and you can just make the types an instance of `Equatable` to get the sort of thing you’re looking for. (You probably don’t need `Equatable` too, since it looks like the built in `Eq` type class.)

Comment: From the naming of the C# involved, it looks like you're implementing equality of a [DDD](http://amzn.to/WBCwx7) Entity. While DDD Entities are characterised by long-lived IDs, it makes no sense to override `Equals` by comparing only a contained `ID`. I explicitly write this, since I once helped to spread that misunderstanding, but I've since realised that this was a bad idea; a discussion with Eric Evans confirmed this. In FP you should strongly favour structural (Value Object) equality.

Comment: My point being: this isn't even good design in C# (and neither is it in Haskell). Don't do it.

Comment: `(==) :: (Entity key) -> (Entity key) -> Bool` is not a valid Haskell.

Comment: I think you understand classes the wrong way. Actually classes are a meta-level higher than C# classes.

Answer (score 3):

As several commenters have pointed out, typclasses in Haskell are a very different concept than classes in object oriented language like C#. [This article](https://wiki.haskell.org/OOP_vs_type_classes#Type_classes_vs_classes) does a better job of explaining the difference than I could ever do myself, and I strongly recommend you read it, but the gist is that when you define an OO class you are defining a specific data type, with concrete implementations of methods on that type. Haskell typeclasses, on the other hand, are not types themselves, they are abstract interfaces which multiple types can implement. In particular, **typeclasses carry no implementations of the functions they declare**. In a sense, this is the entire point of typeclasses. They allow you to write code which can operate on multiple different types that implement similar functionality without having to care about which implementation you're working with at any given time, similar to duck typing or Java's abstract classes. Because of all of this, the idea of using the same name for methods in two different typeclasses is never good idea. The only time it ever makes sense to use the same name for different functions in any programming language is if the functions are merely different implementations of the same basic operation, but again, typeclasses carry no implementations. If you are defining different functions in different typeclasses it is because you are describing operations which are entirely separate, regardless of their implementation.

As for your specific case, it sounds like you want `Entity` to be an object carrying certain data which and is associated with a specific implementation of `(==)`. In that case, you actually actually `Entity` to be a data type which *implements* `Equatable` (or preferably `Eq` from the standard library which has exactly the same definition). This way, when you use `==` to compare objects of type `Entity`, they will be compared using the specific definition of `==` you have given when you implemented `Equatable` (or `Eq`) for `Entity`, and when you use `==` on objects of other types it will use those types' respective implementations.

Comment: A typeclass *can* provide a default implementation for any or all of its functions. In particular, two functions can have default implementations in terms of each other.  A good example is the pair `negate` and `(-)` from the `Num` type class, where `negate x = 0 - x` and `x - y = x + negate y`. Defining either one gives you working implementations of both.

Comment: (`Eq` itself, I think, defines `x == y = not (x /= y)` and `x /= y = not (x == y)`, again so that an instance only needs to define one or the other.)

Comment: @chepner Yes there are many subtleties to the typeclass system that I did not cover in my answer. It seems to me that trying to talk about things like default implementations would only obscure the central issue, which is that typeclasses are abstractions over implementations, not implementations themselves.

Answer (score 0):

C# is using one construct to implement two different concepts. Haskell
separates the two; `(==)` is defined by a type class, and the data that uses `(==)` are defined by types.

```
data Entity a = Entity a  -- A new type

instance Eq a => Entity A where  -- An instance of a typeclass for that type
    (Entity x) == (Entity y) = x == y
```

Haskell can derive `Eq` for you, though, saving you the effort
of defining the instance explicitly.

```
data Entity a = Entity a deriving Eq
```